# How to execute a shell script in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have few shell commands that needs to be executed when a build is getting ready. In Jenkins, I have created a Freestyle project with execute shell options as:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /path to kafka folder
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties &
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties &
cd /path to elasticsearch
bin/elasticsearch
```

I am able to execute this shell commands from a local file but not through Jenkins.

Here is the Console output I am seeing in Jenkins:

```
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson2342342342342357656.sh: line 2: cd: /path to kafka folder: Not a directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any help on how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What happens, if you do it from Jenkins? BTW, do I understand it correctly, that you want to start a server script from within Jenkins, which is supposed to keep running even after the Jenkins job ended?

Comment: that is right. I want all the servers to be up and running even after the job finish running.

Answer (score 0):

It is a permission issue. Please check your Jenkins user has enough permission to run this shell commands

Comment: How can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find out what's wrong (e.g. permissions issue; folder doesn't exist; etc), do this:

- Log into the slave node that is executing this job (if there is none defined, it's probably the Jenkins server itself ("master")
- If on "master": become the user that Jenkins runs as (most likely 'jenkins'): `sudo su - jenkins` (if you have sudo/root access), or `su - jenkins` (if you know jenkins's password)
- If the job runs on another slave, find out as which user the Jenkins server connects. Become that user on the slave node.
- `cd /path/to/workspace` (you can find the job's workspace by looking at the console of a job run)
- Now run your commands from a shell as they are in the build step - it may become more apparent on why they fail.